# Solve differential system using Laplace transforms of Sympy: ''Equality' object has no attribute 'as_independent'

Tags: sympy

I am trying to harness Sympy get differential equation systems solutions.

The simplist example, I have the following traditional decay relation of $dX/dt = -kX$

In textbooks this is solved by taking laplace transform of both sides, simplifiy, then apply inverse laplace transform. So it will be X = X0.e^{kt}.

I have defined my equation as follows:

```
from sympy import symbols, Function, Eq, exp, dsolve

# Define the symbols
t, A, K = symbols('t A K')

# Define the dependent variable
A = Function('A')(t)
A

# Define the differential equation
diff_eq = Eq(A.diff(t), -K*A)
diff_eq
```

```
laplace_transform(diff_eq, t, s)
# AttributeError: 'Equality' object has no attribute 'as_independent'
```

However, I found the dsolve function works, even without `inverse_laplace_transform()`

```
# Solve the differential equation
solution = dsolve(diff_eq, A)
solution

# Extract the function from the solution
f = solution.rhs

f_simplified = f.simplify()
f_simplified
```

So my questions are:

- what am I doing wrong that laplace_transform didn't work?
- What can I do if I start having multiple differential equations? In more advanced cases, I will have more that one process in the system, how can I calculate that in Sympy?

Thanks!

Comment: Perform the Laplace transform on the left and right sides separately. You can do this by running `laplace_transform(diff_eq.lhs, t, s)` and `laplace_transform(diff_eq.rhs, t, s)`.

Comment: @jared Thank you! I see this is working partially. By still I have to rearrange and apply inverse_laplace_transform. Can you guide me through that?

Comment: These is also a function called `dsolve` for solving ODEs.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I used it in my question. It looks simpler! Have you tried to use it if you  have multiple processes system? If you have a tutorial for it I would be graitful ^^

Comment: @PPenton instead of defining `diff_eq` as an `Eq`, rearrange the equation and define it as `diff_eq = A.diff(t) + k*A`. Now you can apply the transform directly. Same with the inverse transform.

Comment: @PPenton I'm not sure what you mean by "multiple processes system", but if you mean a system of ODEs, then you an use the [`dsolve_system`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html#sympy.solvers.ode.systems.dsolve_system) function, which is has examples in the documentation.

Comment: The `dsolve` function can solve systems of ODEs. Just pass them in as a list of equations.